# How to send curl request with post data imported from a file

Tags: linux, command-line, curl, http

I have a below curl command which works fine and I get the response back. I am posting json data to an endpoint which gives me response back after hitting it.

```
curl -v 'url' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Origin: url' --data-binary '{"query":"\n{\n  data(clientId: 1234, filters: [{key: \"o\", value: 100}], key: \"world\") {\n    title\n    type\n    pottery {\n      text\n      pid\n      href\n      count\n      resource\n    }\n  }\n}"}' --compressed
```

Now I am trying to read the binary data from `temp.txt` file outside but somehow it doesn't work and I get an error -

```
curl -v 'url' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Origin: url' --data-binary "@/Users/david/Downloads/temp.txt" --compressed
```

Below is the content I have in my `temp.txt` file -

**Original "temp.txt" file**

```
{
  data(clientId: 1234, filters: [{key: "o", value: 100}], key: "world") {
    title
    type
    pottery {
      text
      pid
      href
      count
      resource
    }
  }
}
```

This is the error I am getting -

```
.......
* upload completely sent off: 211 out of 211 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< date: Fri, 28 May 2021 23:38:12 GMT
< server: envoy
< content-length: 0
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 1
<
* Connection #0 to host url left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Also if I copy the exact same content in the `temp.txt` file that I have in my original curl command with `\n` in it then it works fine.

**Updated "temp.txt" file**

Meaning if I keep the content like this in `temp.txt` file then it works fine from my second curl -

```
{"query":"\n{\n  data(clientId: 1234, filters: [{key: \"o\", value: 100}], key: \"world\") {\n    title\n    type\n    pottery {\n      text\n      pid\n      href\n      count\n      resource\n    }\n  }\n}"}
```

It means I need to find a way to convert new lines to `\n` manually from `temp.txt` file before sending the curl request or is there any other way?

Comment: You say `'Content-Type: application/json`, but your original `temp.txt` is definitely not JSON.

Comment: Does it matter in this case? It works fine for my first curl call without any issues but my second curl command only works fine with my `Updated "temp.txt" file`. I am confuse what I should do so that it can work with my `Original "temp.txt" file`.

Comment: Well, if you tell your server you're going to send JSON and then send some garbage at it, what did you expect it to do?

Comment: yeah that I understand but then why it works fine on my first curl request? It shouldn't work for the first case as well right? With that in mind I am just trying to extract body content from outside file instead of hardcoding it in the curl command line.

Comment: Why? `{"query":"\n{\n  data(clientId: 1234, filters: [{key: \"o\", value: 100}], key: \"world\") {\n    title\n    type\n    pottery {\n      text\n      pid\n      href\n      count\n      resource\n    }\n  }\n}"}` seems like valid enough JSON.

Comment: damn. I am not using right content in my temp.txt file. Now it makes sense. It was a silly mistake on my end. Thanks for helping me with that. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data payload is a JSON document containing a `query` key.  The value of that key is a JSON-encoded document, possibly describing some form of query, which is not in itself a JSON document. Newlines are encoded as `\n` in JSON values, and the JSON parser that the server is using would translate these into literal newlines when it receives your request.

Your attempt to put the decoded `query` value in a separate file and pass that in your `curl` call fails, because the API you are talking to *expects* the data to be a JSON document with a JSON-encoded value for the `query` key.

The correct thing to do to offload the query into a separate file is to do exactly what you did in your last example.  Put the JSON document with the encoded query in a file and reference it using `--data-binary @filename` on the `curl` command line.

```bsh
curl \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-binary '@/Users/david/Downloads/temp.txt' "$API_ENDPOINT"
```